# Calculated field in Excel Pivot Table is incorrect

Tags: excel, pivot

I have raw data that is on a bank account level for vehicle loans.  I have created a pivot table off this with 4 levels of grouping.  Using a colleagues example in another piece of code, I have created a calculated field called GROSS which is calculated as follows:

```
= (ORIGINAL_CAPITAL_AMT*(ORIGINAL_GROSS_RATE-ORIGINAL_PRIME_RATE))/ORIGINAL_CAPITAL_AMT
```

The first issue is that when I do the calculation on account level, this calculated field formula gives me the same result as 
`ORIGINAL_GROSS_RATE-ORIGINAL_PRIME_RATE`
Is this calculating the same thing?  When I look at the formula, it seems to me to be a different calculation due to the position of the brackets but the results of both formulas are identical for every row.

The primary problem though is that the calculated field is not giving me the expected result.  I know what I should get because I have the old example.

Here is an example of the problem.

[LINK TO SAMPLE DATA](http://www.filedropper.com/book5)

Comment: your link is broken

Comment: yes your formula is of the form = (A*(B-C))/A which is A*(B-C)/A which is B-C.

Comment: @Scott Craner - Apologies for the broken link.  Hopefully fixed now.